# How can I destroy multiple game objects at once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out how I can basically stand on a pressure plate and have something that's in the way disappear. I have it working to destroy the object you interact with but not finding any solution to make another object be destroyed.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("PressurePlate"))
    {
      Destroy(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("tree"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Destroy(GameObject.Find("tree"));` or even better, do `private GameObject tree;` then in start do `tree = GameObject.Find("tree");`, then you can just do `Destroy(tree);` and it will be faster that frame. That will destroy the first tree it could find in start

Comment: Thank you! That works, If you add it as an answer happy to accept.

Comment: Kaynn wrote up a good explanation, go ahead and accept theirs :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Destroy(Object)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) takes in an Object, more specifically, a component or a game-object;
(Though nothing would happen if you attempt to destroy a boolean, like what you did in this case; Someone can correct me on that though.)

If you want to destroy the game-object that it has collided with, `Destroy(collision.gameObject)` would do it.

If you want to destroy all GameObjects with a specific tag, you can do [`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(tag)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html), like so:

```
foreach (var gameObj in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Your target tag")){
  Destroy(gameObj);
}
```

There are a few other methods like [`Object.FindObjectsOfType(Type)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) which you can use to fetch all game-objects with a certain type.

But since they are generally slow, I do not highly recommend using those unless you need to;
You can consider caching the respective game-objects somewhere first, and destroying them later.

Comment: Just fyi: a `bool` is not of type [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) not to confuse with [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.object) which also has the alias `object` and is the mother class of everything in c# ;) Passing in a `bool` like OP did shouldn't even compile...